# Ensuring that jQuery is executed only after all PHP has been fully executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, onload, image-loading

I have some jQuery code that works alongside some external PHP, but generally only after a second refresh. The code is designed to **get the dimensions for each image within a list** and **then it re-styles each image** to fit its parent according to its longest side. Upon the first time of loading this page, the jQuery seems to fail to determine the height and width of all images, and so the styling is ignored. **What is the best way to ensure that the jQuery is executed AFTER the images called from the PHP have fully loaded?**

*Scenario:*
I have a page which calls a list of images using an external PHP script. Once the PHP has run, the results are then echoed as HTML inside a div with id "txtHint".

So this PHP (truncated for relevance)...

```
echo "<li><img src='images/".$rowcat['imageurl']. "'><div class='title'>" . $counter . ". " . $rowcat['name'] ."</div></li>";                       
    $counter++;
```

is echoed into this "txtHint" div:

```
<div class="featured-scroller">
<ul>
    <div id="txtHint">
            <li><img src="images/012.jpg"><div class="title">1. Eyemouth Museum </div></li>
            <li><img src="images/014.jpg"><div class="title">2. Edinburgh Museum</div></li>
            // and so on...
    </div>
</ul>
</div>
```

However, once the results are returned I need to check the dimensions of each image instance and style it according to whether the width or height is longer, whilst also keeping its original aspect ratio.

At the moment, I am using the following jQuery:

```
$("#txtHint img").each(function() {
    var imgHeight = $(this).height();
    var imgWidth = $(this).width();

    if(imgHeight > imgWidth)
        {
            $(this).css({'height':'100%', 'width':'auto'});
        }
    else
        {
            $(this).css({'height':'auto', 'width':'100%', 'position':'relative', 'top':'50%', 'margin-top': -imgHeight / 2 + 'px', 'display':'inline-block'});
        }
});
```

It should be mentioned that the external PHP script is called from within a JavaScript within the page head. I'm not sure if that makes a difference.

The current code works, but not the first time. I've tried $(window).load etc, as well as calling it within the mentioned JavaScript that calls the PHP script, but the problem persists.

See the following JSfiddle for a working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/EMPqW/

Comment: Do you aware with client-server model?

Comment: Your JavaScript is always executed after the page has been served to the browser. That means that your JS is always after PHP (except if you run some AJAX calls). Try $(function () { /* your code here */ });

Comment: This is wholly to do with image dimensions only being available after each image has loaded. It is nothing to do with the execution order of PHP and javascript. The issue would be identical with hand-coded HTML (PHP not involved). Jack's/elclanrs's answers below stand the best chance of success.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. Apologies for the slightly newbie question - I'm fairly new (as you probably noticed) to both languages. However, by implementing $(window).load I find that nothing happens.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit confusing. What you're really asking here as far as I understand is how to make sure images are loaded to calculate their dimensions accurately.

The PHP code is irrelevant because PHP will always be interpreted before JavaScript. The server will output HTML and JS will see that but not the original PHP. This is how server-client model works.

To make sure your images are loaded before manipulating them you can use the `load` event of the `window` object.

```
$(window).load(function(){ //images were loaded });
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//your code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure that all images have loaded you could use the `.load()` event:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    // document and images should have loaded by now.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually if you need to check that image complete loaded(it often need when you render image src in javascript, but looks also needed in your case) and anything else not help you may want to place handler `load()` on image, before process it, here is demo:

```
$("#txtHint img").each(function() {
    $t = $(this);

    function image_process() {
        var imgHeight = $t.height();
        var imgWidth = $t.width();

        if (imgHeight > imgWidth) {
            $t.css({
                'height': '100%',
                'width': 'auto'
            });
        }
        else {
            $t.css({
                'height': 'auto',
                'width': '100%',
                'position': 'relative',
                'top': '50%',
                'margin-top': -imgHeight / 2 + 'px',
                'display': 'inline-block'
            });
        }
    }
    if (this.complete) {
        image_process()
    } else {
        $t.one('load',image_process);
    }
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/EMPqW/5/ however, in example both `$(window).load()` and `$(document).ready()` not use this handler.

Answer (score 0):

Before using the load event, which is what you need here, make sure you are running a recent version of jquery. Earlier versions didnt implement it very well across different browsers.